# How to find token type given contract address?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, tokens

Given a contract address is there a way to find the type of the contract?

I want to find the following information about the contract

1. Is it a contract for sure or is it an account?
2. Is the contract of type ERC20 or ERC721 or something else, basically the contract type?

Am sure that if we are able to figure out 2, then 1 is intuitive.
Note: I am looking for solution by directly interacting with the blockchain ethereum mainnet or bsc, not through etherscan.io or other platforms.

Please help !

Comment: Unsure how to check number one. As for number 2, you would have to define a lot more in detail how you would define for example an ERC20 contract. It's actually a very tricky topic - is it for example enough that it has all the required functions, or do the functions have to have certain implementation also

Comment: Lets say I just want to find if its an NFT, and nothing complicated, just ERC721 and ERC1150 then would I have to call each method  exposed by the contract and see it everything is implemented ?